# On first run Consumer<Answers> throws error

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a provider that gets an answer from a sqlite database.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../models/answer.dart';
import '../helpers/answer_db_helper.dart';

class Answers with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Answer> _answers = [];
  bool newAnswer;
  Answer _answer;

  Answer get selectedAnswer {
    return _answer;
  }

  List<Answer> get answers {
    return _answers;
  }

  Future<void> fetchSelectedAnswer(reportId, questionId) async {
    AnswerDBHelper answerDBHelper = AnswerDBHelper();
    _answers = await answerDBHelper.getAnswerByReportIdAndQuestionId(
        reportId, questionId);
    if (_answers.length == 0) {
      newAnswer = true;
      _answer = new Answer();
    } else {
      newAnswer = false;
      _answer = _answers[0];
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  setAnswer(type) {
    _answer.remedialType = type;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  setComment(text) {
    _answer.comment = text;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Im my AnswerScreen through didChangeDependancies()

```
@override
  void didChangeDependencies() async {
    if (!_dataLoaded) {
      final routeArgs =
          ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map<String, Object>;
      sectionName = routeArgs['sectionName'];
      questionId = routeArgs['id'];
      reportId = routeArgs['reportId'];
      selectedQuestion = routeArgs['selectedQuestion'];
      await Provider.of<Answers>(context, listen: false)
          .fetchSelectedAnswer(reportId, questionId);
    }
    _dataLoaded = true;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

I check for an answer and update _answer value in the provider with the answer in the db or create a new blank answer with only the remedialType set if it doesn't exist.

```
class Answer {
  int id;
  int reportId;
  int questionId;
  String remedialType;
  String comment;
  String pictureFilename;
  String pictureUrl;

  Answer({
    this.id,
    this.reportId,
    this.questionId,
    this.remedialType = "Do Not Include",
    this.comment,
    this.pictureFilename,
    this.pictureUrl,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    var map = <String, dynamic>{
      'id': id,
      'report_id': reportId,
      'question_id': questionId,
      'remedial_type': remedialType,
      'comment': comment,
      'picture_filename': pictureFilename,
      'picture_url': pictureUrl,
    };
    return map;
  }

  Answer.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    id = map['ID'];
    reportId = map['REPORT_ID'];
    questionId = map['QUESTION_ID'];
    remedialType = map['REMEDIAL_TYPE'];
    comment = map['COMMENT'];
    pictureFilename = map['PICTURE_FILENAME'];
    pictureUrl = map['PICTURE_URL'];
  }
}
```

In a widget that is inside

```
Consumer<Answers>(builder: (context, answerData, child)
```

I check for the answerData.selectedAnswer.remedialType value with

```
Checkbox(
  value:
    (answerData.selectedAnswer.remedialType ==                                     
     "Do Not Include")
       ? true
       : false,
  checkColor: Colors.white,
  activeColor: Colors.purple[600],
  onChanged: (value) {
  if (value == true) {
    setState(() {
     answerData.setAnswer("Do Not Include");
     });
    }
  },
)
```

This is done for four separate checkbox widgets.

It all works fine but on the first run when I select the first question and the AnswerScreen loads with all the correct data but I get this error in the debug console.

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Consumer<Answers>(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<Answers>]):
The getter 'remedialType' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: remedialType
The relevant error-causing widget was
Consumer<Answers>
package:inspect/screens/answer_screen.dart:60
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
#1      _AnswerScreenState.build.<anonymous closure>
package:inspect/screens/answer_screen.dart:101
#2      Consumer.buildWithChild
package:provider/src/consumer.dart:175
#3      SingleChildStatelessWidget.build
package:nested/nested.dart:260
#4      StatelessElement.build
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4701
...
```

It seems that the answerData.selectedAnswer value is not set in the provider until after the check.

Subsequent answer selections work as intended with the correct checkbox being enabled and no error.

Am have only been using Flutter for about 3 weeks so I am a novice but can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the value of `_answer` *is* null when you instantiate `Answers`, therefore `selectedAnswer` will also be null until the underlying variable is assigned a value. You should assign an initial value through a constructor, like this:

```
class Answers with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Answer> _answers = [];
  bool newAnswer;
  Answer _answer;

  Answers(this._answer); 
  /* etc... */
}
```

Then, instantiate the `Answers` while passing an initial value for `_answer`.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah so as you mentioned, the problem is that the value of `_answer` (`selectedAnswer`), is null until the first time someone selects a check box.

You should add a check inside the `Checkbox` widget's `value` property, to see if the `selectedAnswer` is `null` and return false if it is.

```
value:
    (answerData.selectedAnswer!=null && answerData.selectedAnswer.remedialType ==                                     
     "Do Not Include")
       ? true
       : false
```

That will set the value to `false` if the `selectedAnswer` is `null`

Comment: Thank you.  This does work but I had to add the check in 5 different places.

Comment: So i that case, you should consider creating a separate widget for the checkbox and iterate over a list (of possible answer) to create all of them, rather than creating each one separately.